# Find the y that verifies this Differentail Equation $x^2 y'' - xy'+6y=12x$ with x>0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$x^2 y'' - xy'+6y=12x$

$x(y''x-y')=6(2x-y)$

didn't know how to continue from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $y(x)=u(\ln(x))\quad$ this is motivated by groups $x^py^{(p)}$

The ODE becomes $u''(\ln(x))-2u'(\ln(x))+6u(\ln(x))=12x$

Or similarly $u''-2u'+6u=12e^x$

The characteristic equation $r^2-2r+6=0$ gives roots $1\pm\sqrt{5}$

The particular solution with RHS is given by $ae^x$ with $a-2a+6a=12\iff a=\frac{12}5$

Thus $u(x)=e^x(c_1\cos(\sqrt{5}x)+c_2\sin(\sqrt{5}x)+\frac{12}5)$

Going back to $y$ we get $y(x)=x(c_1\cos(\sqrt{5}\ln x)+c_2\sin(\sqrt{5}\ln x)+\frac{12}5)$

Comment: Shouldnt it be $x^2 u′′(ln(x) - 2x u′(ln(x)) +6u(ln(x))=12x$ ?

Comment: you have to apply the chain rule while derivating, $\ln(x)$ brings $\frac 1x$ and $\frac 1{x^2}$ factors that cancel with the $x$ factors on numerator.

Answer (score 0):

The left side has the coefficient structure of an Euler-Cauchy DE. This gives basis solutions for the homogeneous equation of $x\cos(\sqrt5\ln x)$ and $x\sin(\sqrt5\ln x)$.

As the right side is not composed of these basis solutions, you can find a particular solution using the trial $y_p=Ax$.

Comment: Sorry but where did those root 5's came from?

Comment: @GeorgeDaravigkas.Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=e^t$, then this equation transforms to $$(D^2-2D-6)y(t)=12e^t ~~~(1`)$$, where $D=dy/dt$. Let $D=m$ in (1), we get the characteristic roots as $m=(1\pm \sqrt{5} i)$. So the general solution is $$y_g(t)= e^t [A \sin(\sqrt{5} t)+ B \cos (\sqrt{5} t)]= x [A \sin (\sqrt{5} \ln x)+ B \cos(\sqrt{5}\ln x)]=y_g(x).$$ The particular solution is obtained as $$y_p(t)=12\frac{e^t}{(1)^2-2(1)+6}=\frac{12}{5} e^t.$$ Hence $y_p(x)=\frac{12}{5} x.$ The total solution is $y(x)=y_g(x)+y_p(x)$